# Add a route from an Index page that retains the :id param similar to show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Beginner question here.  I have added another column to the displayed table for a resource index, and I can't figure out how to set up the routing so that when that link is clicked for a specific resource object it goes to the page: resource/run/id_number (where run is the name of the link I added).  I have a view file and controller method for run already, and that part works so what the heck do I have to name the route to get it to work that way.

I've been trying things of the form: match 'route' to:resource_controller#run

But no luck.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already created a Rails resource, you'll probably want to follow RESTful conventions as closely as possible for any additional actions you want to route to your controller.

The best way to do is to create a `member` block and add `run` as a resource:

```
resources :resource_name do
    member do
        get 'run'
    end
end
```

This creates a route like this (from `rake routes`):

```
run_resource_name GET    /resource_names/:id/run(.:format)                   resource_names#run
```

Overall, this is considered preferable to a routing pattern like `resource/run/:id_number` since it follows the conventions of your CRUD routes.

Comment: Thanks!  Any explanation for the structure/functionality of this would also be much appreciated.

Comment: You can find a lot of information by scanning through the commented sections in `routes.rb` or reading the canonical Rails docs. But basically, `resources :resource_name` is creating all the routes you need for RESTful routing. `run` is not a CRUD action, so there's no `run` route. You'll need to add it as a _member_ so that you can pass an `id` to the route. I would suggest reading up on the difference between _member_ and _collection_, since they'll both come in handy. Finally, I would encourage you to try writing routes and using `rake routes` in the console to see what's generated.

Comment: Thanks again! I can't yet upvote due to lack of reputation but I'll keep it in mind.